# clients = self.AVAILABLE_CLIENTS[name] KeyError: 'requests' flask authlib client

Tags: authlib

good day everybody,

having some issues with flask and authlib. Bellow snip of my flash code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("static")
app.config.from_object('config')

oauth = OAuth(app)
webex = oauth.register(name='WEBEX', redirect_uri='http://webapp.dcloud.cisco.com:5000/AuthWebex', client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'spark:all'
    } )

config.py
import os

WEBEX_CLIENT_ID='C3a256be511cdf07e19f272960c44a214aec14b727b108e4f10bd124d31d2112c'
WEBEX_CLIENT_SECRET='secret'
WEBEX_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/access_token'
WEBEX_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:5000/AuthWebex'
WEBEX_SCOPE='spark:all'
```

when running above code I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/tneumann/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/integrations/flask_client/oauth_registry.py", line 61, in register
    self.use_oauth_clients()
  File "/Users/tneumann/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/integrations/_client/oauth_registry.py", line 49, in use_oauth_clients
    clients = self.AVAILABLE_CLIENTS[name]
KeyError: 'requests'
```

looked at examples and did some research, no luck. Can't find any solution...

thanks in adv.

Tobi

UPDATE: 
per comment bellow here the latest code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import os
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("static")
app.config.from_object('config')
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

oauth = OAuth(app)
oauth.register(
        'webex',
            api_base_url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1',
            authorize_url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/authorize',
            access_token_url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/access_token',
            redirect_uri='http://webapp.dcloud.cisco.com:5000/AuthWebex',
            scope='spark:all')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    """Entry point; the view for the main page"""
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    return render_template('authorize.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    #redirect_uri = url_for('AuthWebex', _external=True)
    redirect_uri = 'http://webapp.dcloud.cisco.com:5000/AuthWebex'
    print(redirect_uri)
    return oauth.webex.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/AuthWebex')
def AuthWebex():
    #print(request.__dict__)
    token = oauth.webex.authorize_access_token( authorization_response=request.url,
                                                redirect_uri='http://webapp.dcloud.cisco.com:5000/AuthWebex',
                                                client_id='C3a256be511cdf07e19f272960c44a214aec14b727b108e4f10bd124d31d2112c',
                                                client_secret='secret',
                                                )
    print("Token: ", token)
    resp = oauth.webex.get('https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/people/me')
    profile = resp.json()
    print(profile)
    # do something with the token and profile
    return '<html><body><h1>Authenticated</h1></body></html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

oauth.webex.authorize_access_token function throws and error when called without the parameters. which is strange as most examples I found exactly do that. 
client_id and client_secret are set via the config.py file. This works for the oauth.register function but not for the authorize_access_token.

Additional problem is that even with the parameters, it produces a valid token. When I call the get function I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/tneumann/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 317, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/Users/tneumann/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/Users/tneumann/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/authlib/integrations/requests_client/oauth2_session.py", line 41, in __call__
    raise UnsupportedTokenTypeError(description=description)
authlib.integrations._client.errors.UnsupportedTokenTypeError: unsupported_token_type: Unsupported token_type: 'token_type'
```

here is the format of the token returned from authorize_access_token function

```
Token:  {'access_token': 'YWIzNGU3<secret>tNDQ5_PF84_7cc07dbd-<secret>-5877334424fd', 'expires_in': 1209599, 'refresh_token': 'MjU2ZDM4N2Et<secret>ZmItMTg5_PF84_7cc07dbd-<secret>877334424fd', 'refresh_token_expires_in': 7722014, 'expires_at': 1574863645}
```

went through the docs, the code on github and debugging in pycharm with no luck, help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you install `requests`?

Comment: Update: made some progress, bellow the flow that works to get a token. Must be missing something really important. All the examples I looked at assume that one can call i.e. token = oauth.google.authorize_access_token() without any parameters. If I do so response complains that client_id and client_secret among other parameters are missing. As shown in the code bellow found a way to fix that - still wondering about the reasons.

Comment: yes I did install requests

Comment: @lepture any more insights per my update?

Comment: You need to configure the client_id and client_secret in your Flask config. Checkout the documentation: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html

See configuration part.

Comment: @lepture, I think I did, tell me if I am missing something obvious. Checked this example https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/tree/master/flask-google-login where the config parameters are in config.py which is exactly the same I did (see above). The strange thing is that it works for the register but not for the authorize_access_token and get. Example above states that there are only 2 parameters are set (CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET). All other functions are called without any parameters. So again maybe I am missing something really obvious or don't understand the doc :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this AuthWebex is not a standard OAuth service. The response has no `token_type`. We can fix it with Authlib compliance fix:

Check the example here:

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#compliance-fix-for-oauth-2-0

The slack example has the same issue.